# Recursive generic type parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types, type-parameter

I needed some help understanding recursive generics in C#.

I came across this code:

```
public abstract class Value<T> where T : Value<T>
{
    ....
}

public class UserId: Value<UserId>
{
}
```

I am confused by the part where the `Value<T>` is used on both sides of the where clause. Can someone please explain what the code does?

Comment: It's a generic type constraint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: This is C# generic syntax.  Its saying that the abstract class `Value` takes a _generic type parameter_ and that parameter is represented by the variable `T`.  The `where` means that there is a restriction where `T` has to be a type that implements `Value<T>`.  @dee-see has linked the docs which are more detailed, my comment is a quick summary

Comment: These are simple c# generics. You can read about them [here (general generics)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) and [here (generic type constraints)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). If that's not your question you might need to clarify what exactly you don't understand. EDIT: While typing that I got beat by many others so sorry for the repetition :)

Comment: @maccettura I am a bit confused about the part where Value<T> is used on both sides of the where clause. Isnt that recursive?

Comment: @ashwnacharya that part does look a little weird to me.  I assumed it compiled/ran fine though since you didnt mention anything to the contrary.  If your question is about _that_ specifically I think you should edit and re-word your question so a proper answer/discussion can take place

Comment: It's known as a "Curiously recurring template pattern" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). C# examples https://zpbappi.com/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-csharp/ and https://blog.arkanosoft.com/index.php/crtp-c/

Comment: @maccettura Yes, it compiles. The code is from here: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Domain-Driven-Design-with-.NET-Core/blob/master/Chapter07/Marketplace.Framework/Value.cs

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Thank you for the links. They were very helpful. Also, the name gave me something to google more specifically and I learnt something new. If you can submit that as an answer, I would be happy to accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but worth mentioning  - as of C# 9, [covariant returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns) can be used in lieu of CRTP in most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's known as a "[Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)" . C# examples [here](https://zpbappi.com/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-csharp) and [here](https://blog.arkanosoft.com/index.php/crtp-c). Often used for [fluent syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) of interface types in order to keep the generic type "known" to the base implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It a recursive generic type parameter.

It means that T must be a Value of T.

It is normal to found that difficult to understand and I found it is difficult to explain... sorry.

Someone else should be able to explain better.

[Recursive Generics](https://code-maze.com/fluent-builder-recursive-generics/)

[Recursive Generics Restrictions](https://fernandof.wordpress.com/2007/09/23/recursive-generics-restrictions/)

Comment: While this is fine, since you've named the pattern so users can find articles themselves, answers with links to explanations are generally frowned upon. It's better to quote the relevant parts of the articles (if the license is amenable).